# Mapping an ArrayList to a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I am reading in a bunch of long strings from an ArrayList like...

```
Green,Jim,Bob,Dan
Blue,Chris,Al,Jeff
Orange,Mark
```

I want to map these values into a HashMap with the colors as the key and the names as the mapped values.

I figured out how to get the colors as the key, but I am not sure how to get the mapped values as the names.

Code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < namesAndColors.size(); i++) {
        String linetoSplit = namesAndColors.get(i);

        String colors= linetoSplit.split(",")[0];

        hm.put(colors, ***);
        }

    System.out.println(hm);
    }
```

Output right now would be something like:

```
[Green = , Blue= , Orange= ]
```

Desired Output:

```
[Green = Jim Bob Dan, Blue = Chris Al Jeff, Orange = Mark]
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following

```
 String colors= linetoSplit.split(",")[0];
 List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int j = 1; j < linetosplit.lenght; j++)
     temp.add(linetosplit[i]);

  hm.put(colors, temp);
```

I am assuming the Hashmap as `< String, List< String > >` and also assuming your other operation before my added parts are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the JDK do the heavy lifting for you:

```
for (String str : namesAndColors)
    hm.put(str.replaceAll(",.*", ""), Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("^.*?,", "").split(",")));
```

Note the use of the simpler foreach loop.